# Force bootstrap to ignore the larger column heights

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

Is there any way to force Bootstrap so that the first column of the second row is positioned just below the height of its respective column in the previous row?

Currently what happens is that each row takes the height of the largest column.

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4" style="background-color: #f8d7da; height: 100px;">
        First col
      </div>
      <div class="col-4" style="background-color: #d4edda; height: 400px;">
        Second col
      </div>
      <div class="col-4" style="background-color: #cce5ff; height: 300px;">
        Thirth col
      </div>
      <div class="col-4" style="background-color: #a8c4da;">
        Fourth col
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

---

**For example, if i use Flexbox the solution is just like this:**

```
<div className="container">
    <div className="col-4">First col</div>
    <div className="col-4">Second col</div>
    <div className="col-4">Third col</div>
    <div className="col-4">Fourth col</div>
</div>


.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
  grid-gap: 12px;
}

.col-4 {
  background-color: #f8d7da;
  width: 100%;
}

.col-4:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #d4edda;
  grid-row: span 4;
}

.col-4:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: #cce5ff;
  grid-row: span 4; 
}

.col-4:last-child {
  background-color: #a8c4da;
}
```

[image]

Comment: @JeJe yeah it happens the same

Comment: the desired outcome looks like a masonry layout if you wish to have a keyword to help your search before any answer arrives here

Comment: by the way it's worth pointint out that the bootstrap columns layout expect a row to be made of 12 columns.. you have a row of 16 cols instead. That's not a responsive layout. What I mean by that is that you will always see 3 columns whatever is the resolution

Comment: given those condition, the desired result could be obtained just having 3 row's children each with `col-4`and inside the first col just have the 2 divs. But that means the requirement is not clear to begin with or the original layout is wrong because it doesn't address having multiple columns that could be wrapped based on the screen width resolution

Comment: @AlexisDalaiWaldoJiménez, I think I understood what's the results shoudl look like: check this feedle:https://jsfiddle.net/nono_london/tnv9qrfz/9/

Comment: @AlexisDalaiWaldoJiménez: " There is only one < div class="row"" is this a requirement?

Comment: @JeJe yes, that is exactly what i need, but telling bootstrap to do it automatically, not adding more rows between.

Comment: the doc: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/ seems to always use additionnal rows but will see if s.o. finds another way...

Comment: I see you are still chasing the wrong rabbit.. you call them _rows added by bootstrap_ but that's what you are doing using the bootstrap layout. The class `row` is called row because it means a row. If you wish to have multiple columns in a `flex` responsive layout to be arrange next to each other depending on the available width, you don't need rows at all and you should use a different layout. But you are not clear because you showed an example with 4 columns wrapped in a row

Comment: the closest thing to what you are looking for is dropping bootstrap and use vanilla css: `display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;` for the container, and each child being the "column" will need to be sized according to your requirement

Comment: if you wish to actually follow the masonry layout just see here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/masonry/

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="sm-4 col-4">     
        <div class="row">
          <div class=" sm-4 col-4" style="background-color: #f8d7da; height: 100px;">
            First col
          </div>
       </div>
       <div class="row">
         <div class="col-4" style="background-color: #a8c4da;">
           Fourth col
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-4" style="background-color: #d4edda; height: 400px;">
        Second col
     </div>
     <div class="col-4" style="background-color: #cce5ff; height: 300px;">
        Thirth col
     </div>      
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```